Spring Kafka RequestReply ListenableFuture Threads Park Issue
Application Overview

We have 2 Microservices integrated via Apache Kafka Topic .
Microservice 1 [MS1] Sends Message To Microservice 2 [MS2] via Kafka TOpic using Spring Kafka Request-Reply Template
& Waits on REply Topic with Correlation id
MS2 Upon Receiving the Message, process Business logics and puts response to Response Topic
in a Partition which was sent in Header REPLY_PARTITION, REPLY_TOPIC



Tech Stack
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.7.12
'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-clients', version: '3.5.1'
Challenge Faced



We are able to Receive Response in normal Scenario getting
correlated, some times in Huge Load, inspite of MS2 sending
responses, MS1 is still waiting for response




we ran a Load Test iN MS1 - Lot of Application Threads going to park state in Following method




***ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord = (ConsumerRecord<String, String>)sendAndReceive.get();***





We also simulated using Java Load Generator to call Same Service class in MS1 and see where it is causing issue. Ref See Load Generator.java enclosed below




Unable to find cause of the Issue , No Error in Kafka,Zookeeper Logs or console



Why Threads are park state listenable future
Additional Information
**KafkaInvoker**
@Component
public class KafkaInvoker extends ServiceInvoker {
    static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(KafkaInvoker.class);

    @Autowired
    ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> kafkaTemplate;
    
    @Autowired
    private ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> replyContainer;

    @Value("${edge.timeout.interval:300000}")
    private long edgetimeoutsec;

    @Autowired
    TransformationServicess_sb tss;

    public static JSONObject getEPConfig(String srvName) throws RuntimeException {
        String epConfigName;
        JSONObject confMapping = null;
        try {
            epConfigName = getEPConfigName(srvName);
            confMapping = getJSONFromConfigs(epConfigName, "managerId", getConfigArray());
        } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Error getting ep config for service mapping : " + srvName);

        }
        return confMapping;
    }

    public String sendToQueueKafkaTemplate(String key, String srvMapping, String message, JSONObject headers,
            String edgereq) {
        String response = null;
        try {
            String topic = getTopicName(srvMapping);
            // String requestReplyTopic = DEFAULT_REPLY_TOPIC;
            String requestReplyTopic = getTopicName(srvMapping + "_REPLY_TOPIC");
            logger.debug("Sending message to topic->" + topic);
            logger.debug("Response topic for requestReplyTemplates :" + requestReplyTopic);
            // ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, key,
            // message);

            String corrId = headers.getString("messageId");
            logger.debug(" CorrilationId " + corrId);
            kafkaTemplate.setCorrelationIdStrategy((kvProducerRecord -> new CorrelationKey(corrId.getBytes())));
            kafkaTemplate.setDefaultReplyTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(edgetimeoutsec));

            // create producer record
            Integer partitionId = getAssignedPartition(requestReplyTopic);
            ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic, corrId, message);

            // set reply topic in header
            record.headers().add(new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.REPLY_TOPIC, requestReplyTopic.getBytes()));
            record.headers().add(new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.REPLY_PARTITION, partitionId.toString().getBytes()));
            if (headers != null) {
                Iterator<String> keys = headers.keys();
                while (keys.hasNext()) {
                    String ki = keys.next();
                    record.headers().add(new RecordHeader(ki, headers.getString(ki).getBytes()));

                }
            }
            
            RequestReplyFuture<String, String, String> sendAndReceive = kafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(record);
    
            SendResult<String, String> sendResult = sendAndReceive.getSendFuture().get();
                    sendResult.getProducerRecord().headers()
                    .forEach(header -> logger.trace(header.key() + ":" + new String(header.value())));
            logger.info("Sent_Msg_To_Topic_ACK::tpc=[" + topic + "],msgId=[" + corrId + "],ttkn=[" + timeElapsed
                    + "ms],record_timestamp=[" + sendResult.getRecordMetadata().timestamp() + "],partitionID=["
                    + sendResult.getRecordMetadata().partition() + "]");

            logger.info("waiting for response at topic [" + requestReplyTopic + "] ,partitionID=[" + partitionId
                    + "] with corrId : " + corrId);
            // get consumer record
            //ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord = sendAndReceive.completable().get(60000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
// return consumer value >>>>>>>>>>ISSUE AREA
            **ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord = sendAndReceive.completable().get();**
            
            response = consumerRecord.value();
            logger.info("Got response for coorId : " + corrId);
            // logger.trace("Got response for coorId : "+corrId+" as : "+response);
            LoggerUtility.masked_trace(response, "json", "Got response for coorId : " + corrId + " as : ", logger);

        } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
            logger.error("ERROR sending message with error :" + e.getLocalizedMessage(), logger);
         
            response = "ERR10";
        
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException  e) {
            logger.error("ERROR sending message with error :" + e.getLocalizedMessage(), logger);
          response = "ERR11";
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
             response = "ERR12";
        }
        return response;
    }


    public static <E> Optional<E> getRandom(Collection<E> e) {
        return e.stream().skip((int) (e.size() * Math.random())).findFirst();
    }

    private Integer getAssignedPartition(String requestReplyTopic) {
        Optional<TopicPartition> tp = getRandom(replyContainer.getAssignedPartitions());
        logger.info("Partition assigned :[" + tp.get().partition() + "]");
        return tp.get().partition();
    }
}



    package com.myorg;
  

@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfig {

    private static String bootstrapServers;
    public static JSONUtill util = new JSONUtill();
    private static final int DEFAULT_KAFKA_PORT = 9092;
    private static final String DEFAULT_KAFKA_HOST = "localhost";

    static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(KafkaConfig.class);
    static {

        JSONObject confMapping = KafkaInvoker.getEPConfig("InbProducer");
        String host = (String) util.getObjectUsingPath(confMapping, "connectionDetails/host");
        int port = (int) util.getObjectUsingPath(confMapping, "connectionDetails/port");
        try {
            ServiceInvoker.checkKafkaServerStatus();
        } catch (StartUpException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Application Startup Failed ,caused " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        if (host == null) {
            host = DEFAULT_KAFKA_HOST;
            logger.warn("host not confugured for Kafka producer!!, using default host : " + DEFAULT_KAFKA_HOST);
        }
        if (port == 0) {
            port = DEFAULT_KAFKA_PORT;
            logger.warn("port not confugured for Kafka producer!!, using default port : " + DEFAULT_KAFKA_PORT);
        }

        bootstrapServers = host + ":" + port;
        logger.info("kafka brokerip :" + bootstrapServers);

    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {

        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "lz4");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, "20");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, "16384");
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, requestreplygorup);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, requestreplygorup + "_edge_client");
//      /props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 100);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG,"900000");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG,"100");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG,"45000");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MIN_BYTES_CONFIG,"1");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG,"true");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,"earliest");
        
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

    @Bean // register and configure replying kafka template
    public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> replyingTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, String> pf,
            ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> repliesContainer) {
        ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> replyTemplate = new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(pf, repliesContainer);
        replyTemplate.setDefaultReplyTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        replyTemplate.setSharedReplyTopic(true);
        return replyTemplate;
    }

    @Value("${requestreplygorup:requestreplygorup}")
    private String requestreplygorup;

    @Value("${DEFAULT_REPLY_TOPIC:SENDER_RESPONSE_NOTIFICATION}")
    private String default_reply_topic;

    @Bean // register ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer bean
    public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> repliesContainer(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> containerFactory) {
        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> repliesContainer = containerFactory
                .createContainer(default_reply_topic);
        repliesContainer.getContainerProperties().setGroupId(requestreplygorup);
        repliesContainer.setAutoStartup(false);
        repliesContainer.setConcurrency(consCount);
        return repliesContainer;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(), new StringDeserializer());

    }

    @Value("${consCount:1}")
    private int consCount;

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        logger.info("Setting count concurrent ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory to :[" + consCount + "]");
        factory.setConcurrency(consCount);
        factory.setReplyTemplate(kafkaTemplate());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setIdleBetweenPolls(98L);
        logger.info("fatory impl :["+factory.getContainerProperties().getIdleBetweenPolls()+"]");
        // factory.setBatchListener(false);

        return factory;
    }
}

